# create view or table or create an entry to auto generate a row in another table?

Tags: mysql, view, triggers

I have a table store all blocktrade ( say over $500,000 per transaction, it could either be bid transaction(direct buy), ask transactino(direct sell), as shown above. I am going to make summary of the results each day. But due to very large amount of data in BlockTrade(hundreds thousand rows of data and even more), I will only make use of the summary data as expected to be done below.

The problem is it is very slow when I select * from [View], shall I create a table storing the data output as historical data is not needed to be query again from BlockTrade Table.

Table:BlockTrade

Code | DateTime | Price | Order(Buy=1, Sell=-1) | Vol | Amount

Part of SQL to sum the relevant transaction of same day same stock:
... -> sum(case when Order = 1 then Amount else 0 end) ... -> convert to results

View: Summary1

Code | Date | Price | TotalBuyVol| TotalBuyAmount | TotalSellVol| TotalSellAmount

By each price of each stock per day, it will have a summary.

View: Summary2

Code | Date | TotalBuyVol| TotalBuyAmount | TotalSellVol| TotalSellAmount | NetAmount

By each stock per day, not by each price, summary on total buy and sell volume and amount.

Answer (score 0):

If you will be accessing the data frequently. You can create views and access the data with a better performance & easily just by a simple select statement.

```
create view summary1 as (
select CODE, date_format(DateTime,'%d/%m/%Y'), PRICE, sum(buyvol), sum(buyamount),sum(sellvol),sum(sellamount)
from BlockTrade group by CODE, date_format(DateTime,'%d/%m/%Y'), PRICE);

create view summary2 as (
select Code, date_format(DateTime,'%d/%m/%Y'), sum(buyvol), sum(buyamount),sum(sellvol),sum(sellamount), sum(price)
from BlockTrade group by CODE, date_format(DateTime,'%d/%m/%Y')
  );
```

You can access the summary1 & summary2 just as follows:

```
select * from summary1; 
select * from summary2;
```

Here you go with the [sqlfiddle 
link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/332cf/1)

Comment: I searched over the forum and found that some people said the performance won't be improved a lot as it is just a stored sql statement. if I don't want to query the view again (as it still need to run the query each time, is it good to just store the results of the summary into a table?) As the BlockTrade table will be updated each day. I won't need to query the blocktrade table after the summary created. I just need the summary table for calculation. There are 1700 stocks in the database.

Comment: yeah, i agree. You cannot see a huge difference in performance. One more reason for using views is ease of convenience & security. You can find n number of articles on views vs select statement. But I see your numbers are very less. Mysql has the capability to do complex joins on millions of records so quickly than you imagine if you perfectly use the concepts like indexing & partitioning.

Comment: can u help me how to create the row insert into a table say "TxSummary" of the results getting from the select statement "select Code, datE_format..."? I will run it day by day automatically. then I could just retrieve from table of the summary fast. thanks.

Comment: it's pretty simple just as the usual insert statement (You can also include where conditions on the select statement to filter say, date specific data)

"insert into TxSummary (Code, DateTime) select Code, DateTime from BlockTrade;"

sql fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/333f3/1